# Зависает при установке приложений через терминал!

Tags: pantheon-terminal

Зависает при установке приложений через терминал[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWhEK.png)

Stuck on 16% !?

i did use sudo apt install pidgin...

Comment: Please use google translator and be more specific on what yout problem is, this is an english stack exange site.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было нажать Tab, выбрать OK и все...

---

Press `Tab` and then press `Enter`

Answer (score 1):

Click TAB and *OK* wilk highlight. Then press Enter and That's it. :)